# Using Turan's theorem to calculate a bound for triangle free graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Using $$ \alpha(G) \ge \frac{n^2}{2\mathbb{E}(G) + n} $$  prove that any graph on n vertices with no
triangles has at most $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges.

$\alpha(G)$ is the maximum size of independent vertices in G.

Comment: What is $\alpha(G)$?

Comment: It is stated on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G^{'}$ be a triangle free graph, and that $G$ is its complement.

From this we get that $\alpha(G) \le 2$ (Why?)

Finally we get $$\mathbb{E}(G) \ge \frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{n}{2}$$

After one more step, the proof is finished for $G^{'}$. (How?)